# How to apply multiple CSS translate value for one element

Tags: css, transform, transition

I want to translate my placeholder text Y-axis upto -30px and X-axis upto -100px on input field focus. Means go to UP 30px and than go to LEFT 100px as I have mentioned on the below attached picture.

When I'm trying to make this animation the both value, means X and Y at the same time is not working. I want to make the text **first go to top** and after that **go to left** but in my case it is directly going to the left point without going to top.

[image]

This one is not working for me - **transform: translateY(-30px) translateX(-100px);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little bit of a hack combining two ways of transforming elements and adding a delay.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label {
  transition: translate 0.5s linear 0s, transform 0.2s linear 0.5s;
}

.input-container:focus-within label {
  translate: -100px 0;
  transform: translateY(-30px);
  transition: translate 0.5s linear 0.2s, transform 0.2s linear 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an animation with keyframes to define that motion.

```
@keyframes move {
    0%   {transform: translate(0px 0px);}
    50%  {transform: translate(0px -30px);}
    100% {transform: translate(-100px -30px);}
}
```

Then you can play the animation as necessary to get that motion.